# TCP: python client and perl server - receive line by line

Tags: python, perl, sockets, tcp

perl_server.pl

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Sys::Hostname;
use Socket;


my($addr)=inet_ntoa((gethostbyname(hostname))[4]);



# auto-flush on socket
$| = 1;

# creating a listening socket
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => $addr,
    LocalPort => '7777',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 5,
    Reuse => 1
);
die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $socket;
print "server waiting for client connection on $addr:7777\n";


# waiting for a new client connection
my $client_socket = $socket->accept();

# get information about a newly connected client
my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
print "connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";
while(1)
{
    # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
    my $data = "";
    $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
    print "received data: $data\n";

    if ($data eq "done") {
        last;
    }else {
        # write response data to the connected client
        $data = "ok";
        $client_socket->send($data);
    }

}



# notify client that response has been sent
shutdown($client_socket, 1);
$socket->close();
```

python_client.py

```
import socket
import sys
import time

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 7777)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)


cnt = 0
while True:
    try:
        cnt += 1

        #time.sleep(1)
        # Send data
        message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
        print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
        sock.sendall(message)

        if cnt > 10000:
            sock.sendall("done")
            break
    except Exception, msg:
        continue


print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
sock.close()
```

So, the above code works fine but I would like it so that `perl_client.pl` recieves one line at a time

For example, right now the following code,

```
$client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
print "received data: $data\n";
```

`$data` contains multiple lines of `'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'`
i would like so that `$data` contains ONE line of `'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'`

Now this message from client may change so i dont know if simply changing 1024 would suffice.

any suggestions?

Comment: **wrong while** check this https://www.ccsf.edu/Pub/Perl/perlipc/TCP_Servers_with_IO_Socket.html  mean : `while accpeting and while client isAlive` and i delete my old comment.

Comment: @dsgdfg when i changed to that, the file handle was receiving nothing. hmm